# How to merge more than one array and convert into json array using php

Tags: php

I have been trying to merge 3 arrays into one array but instead of merging values inside array it just joining array into an array

My code

```
array_push($array_pricenew,array('firstvalue'=>"first value",'second'=>"second value",'third'=>"third"));
array_push($array_pricenew,array('four'=>"four value"));
array_push($array_pricenew,array('five'=>"five value"));
array_push($array_pricenew,array('six'=>"six value"));
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [one] => "one value"
            [two] => "two value"
            [three] => "three value"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [four] => "four value"
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [five] => "five value"
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [six] => "six value"
        )

)
```

Needed output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [one] => "one value"
            [two] => "two value"
            [three] => "three value"
            [four] => "four value"
            [five] => "five value"
            [six] => "six value"
        )

)
```

Notes

1. I need to merge three arrays into one as shown in the above example
2. suggest me the php code i tried only array push

Comment: array_merge, as its name, merges arrays

Comment: i need to merge its values into a single array

Comment: Yep we know. That's why array_merge was mentioned. Seriously, go read the documentation for array_merge and look at the examples. array_combine might also help you. Did you try just [putting your question title into google](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+merge+more+than+one+array+and+convert+into+json+array+using+php)? Probably would have been quicker than posting here....and you'd get pretty much the same outcome. Judging by the results, I don't think this is a problem which needs a new answer.

Comment: If the keys are duplicated, how do you suppose your program should handle it?

Comment: `json_encode([array_merge(...$allArrays)])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't understand why they have to be within a single array key (0), but I believe this would output something pretty close to what you're describing:

```php
$arr1 = ['firstvalue' => "first value", 'second' => "second value", 'third' => "third"];
$arr2 = ['four' => "four value"];
$arr3 = ['five' => "five value"];
$arr4 = ['six' => "six value"];

echo json_encode([array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4)]);;
```

Result:

```json
[{"firstvalue":"first value","second":"second value","third":"third","four":"four value","five":"five value","six":"six value"}]
```